# How long should a the Google change of address tool take?

Tags: google, google-search-console, domains, google-search, change-address-tool

I requested a Google Search Console change of address back in May 2019 but it still hasn't updated on Google.

Just wondering if anyone gone through the process of changing their address and with Google SEO and how long it has taken for it to update?